# C Error: Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c

Buenas, me encuentro atascado con el error del asunto. Estoy probando un código sencillo, pero no me doy cuenta donde esta el error.

El Error se encuentra en el **printf**

```
struct nodoLinea {
    char Caracter;
    struct nodoLinea *Siguiente;
};

typedef struct nodoLinea NodoLinea;
typedef NodoLinea *ptrNodoLinea;


struct nodoColumna {
    struct ptrNodoLinea *Linea;
    struct nodoColuma *ptrSig;
};

typedef struct nodoColumna NodoColumna;
typedef NodoColumna *ptrNodoColumna;

int main ()
{
    ptrNodoLinea ptrL = NULL;
    ptrNodoColumna ptrC = NULL;

    ptrC = malloc(sizeof(struct nodoColumna)); /* crea un nodo */
    ptrL = malloc(sizeof(struct nodoLinea)); /* crea un nodo */

    ptrL->Caracter = 'A';
    ptrL->Siguiente = NULL;

    ptrC->Linea = ptrL;
    ptrC->ptrSig =NULL;

    printf("%c",ptrC->Linea->Caracter);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿en que linea es el error?

Comment: @abrahamhs **El Error se encuentra en el printf**

Comment: y ya intentaste `printf("%c",&ptrC->Linea->Caracter);` ???

Comment: Lo acabo de intentar, me sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: A ojo diría que tienes algunos typedef mal definidos (a menos que haya sido un error alcopiar), y algun jaleo con los punteros. Hace años que no uso C, pero al verlo algo me dice que no está bien (aunque compile)

Comment: Por ejemplo, cambia typedef NodoLinea *ptrNodoLinea; por typedef NodoLinea* ptrNodoLinea; y struct ptrNodoLinea *Linea; por struct ptrNodoLinea Linea;  esta última sin asterisco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que estás utilizando typedef para ocultar la estructura y el puntero (algunas personas lo ven como una mala práctica, aunque otros no).

Hiciste las siguientes definiciones:

```
typedef struct nodoLinea NodoLinea;
typedef NodoLinea *ptrNodoLinea;
```

de modo que (ptrNodoLinea) = (struct nodoLinea *).

Después intentas definir la siguiente estructura

```
struct nodoColumna {
    struct ptrNodoLinea *Linea;
    struct nodoColuma *ptrSig;
};
```

pero ¿Qué es struct ptrNodoLinea *? si expandes (por así decirlo) el typedef sería algo así

```
struct struct nodoLinea **Linea
```

lo cual no tiene sentido (struct struct es una construcción inválida), entonces la solución está en quitar el struct como el asterísco en la la variable Linea, de modo que quedaría.

```
struct nodoColumna {
    ptrNodoLinea Linea;
    struct nodoColuma *ptrSig;
};
```

Espero esto resuelva tu problema.

Comment: Me ha servido mucho, gracias. Tienes razón, estaba definiendo un doble struct lo cual como dices no es valido. Muchas gracias de nuevo.